# JAXB Unmarshal a list of objects

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have the following XML that I am trying to unmarshal:

```
<ListOfYear>
    <Requests/>
    <Payload>
        <Year>
            <Value>2013</Value>
        </Year>
        <Year>
            <Value>2012</Value>
        </Year>
        <Year>
            <Value>2011</Value>
        </Year>
        <Year>
            <Value>2010</Value>
        </Year>
        <Year>
            <Value>2009</Value>
        </Year>
        <Year>
            <Value>2008</Value>
        </Year>
    </Payload>
</ListOfYear>
```

My java class looks like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ListOfYear")
public class YearOutput {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Payload")
    @XmlElement(name = "Year")
    private ArrayList<Year> Payload;

    public ArrayList<Year> getPayload() {
        return Payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(ArrayList<Year> payload) {
        Payload = payload;
    }
}
```

Payload should contain a list of year objects:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Year")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD).
public class Year {

    @XmlElement(name = "Value")
    int Value;

    public int getValue() {
        return Value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

I am unmarshaling the XML with the following code:

```
String r = response.getEntity(String.class);
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(YearOutput.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();

YearOutput output = (YearOutput) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(r));
```

I get an output object back just fine, the payload object is always null. I have tried several different approaches with my XML annotation and have not been able to get anything to work. Any help would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**
I thought the name space was inconsequential so I didn't post that part of the code. But @Blaise Doughan suggested I marshal my model and it appears my  namespace may be causing an issue...

Here is the full XML that I need:

```
<ListOfYear xmlns="http://something.com/">
    <Requests/>
    <Payload>
        <Year>
            <Value>2013</Value>
        </Year>
        <Year>
            <Value>2012</Value>
        </Year>
        <Year>
            <Value>2011</Value>
        </Year>
        <Year>
            <Value>2010</Value>
        </Year>
        <Year>
            <Value>2009</Value>
        </Year>
        <Year>
            <Value>2008</Value>
        </Year>
    </Payload>
</ListOfYear>
```

Here is my full model:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ListOfYear", namespace = "http://something.com/")
public class YearOutput {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Payload")
    @XmlElement(name = "Year")
    private ArrayList<Year> Payload;

    public ArrayList<Year> getPayload() {
        return Payload;
    }

    public void setPayload(ArrayList<Year> payload) {
        Payload = payload;
    }
}
```

Now when I marshal my model I am getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:ListOfYear xmlns:ns2="https://something.com/">
    <Payload>
        <Year>
            <Value>2008</Value>
        </Year>
    </Payload>
</ns2:ListOfYear>
```

So what am I doing wrong with my namespace?

**EDIT**
After adding package-info.java everything works perfect!

```
@XmlSchema(
        namespace = "https://something.com/",
        elementFormDefault = XmlNsForm.QUALIFIED)
package example;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlNsForm;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema;
```

Comment: Can you post more of the code, starting with how you create (or obtain) the "response" reference? I suspect that the String (r) does not actually contain what you think it contains (have you tried printing it out to see if it contains your XML?).

Comment: @JStevenPerry the XML in this post is almost a copy past from the output of my code. Thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your annotations need to go on the property (get or set method) instead of the field. If you wish to have them on the field (instance variable), the you need to annotate your class with `@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)`, like you have on your `Year` class.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/06/using-jaxbs-xmlaccessortype-to.html

**UPDATE**

Instead of specifying the namespace on `@XmlRootElement` you will need to leverage a package level `@XmlSchema` annotation (on a class called `package-info`) to match the namespace qualification.

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/jaxb-namespaces.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have tried both but to no avail... however, I feel like the issue is with the actual arraylist and not the Year class. If it was the year class, would I not just have an empty list?

Comment: @ferics2 - If you populate your object model and marshal it (write it to XML) then what does it look like?

Comment: I think you are on to something Blaise. Great tip for debugging. I added my results as an edit on this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a / to the ending Payload tag.

Comment: Sorry, typo... the list was much longer so I cut some out and forgot to close the tag in my edit. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. A it's already mentioned, the XML file should contain
   `</Payload>`
   instead of 
   `<Payload>`
   in the last but one line
2. @XmlElement should be above attribute but not getter in Year class:
   `@XmlElement int Value;`

Comment: I wish that was what was wrong. Tried it to no avail. However, I am curious when should the element tag go over the property vs the getter or setter? I have seen it done both ways.

Answer (score 1):

The element name in XmlElement annotation on getValue is missing. JAXB default behavior is that getValue means **'value'** element, **not 'Value'**. Add the annotation **@XmlElement(name="Value")**

Fix it as in your other code

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Year")
public static Year {

...

    @XmlElement(name="Value")
    public int getValue() {
       return Value;
   }

...

}
```

---

If you also marshal I recommend to add **@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)** to the classes to prevent adding both 'value' and 'Value' elements.

See full working code at package 'wicketstuff/enteam/wicket/examples14/mixed' on
https://repo.twinstone.org/projects/WISTF/repos/wicket-examples-1.4/browse/

Also a test that log into console your XML and parse it back is provided in 'YearOutputTest'